# How to type an object of key: reducerFunctions according to an interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following interface:

```
interface TestState {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}
```

I'm trying to write a generic type that specifies that an object must:

- contain the same keys as a provided interface (e.g TestState)
- for each key, provide a value of a reducer function, with the type specified in TestState as the type of the state itself.

So for example, an object doing this would be like this:

```
const test: StateSlices<TestState> = {
  a: (state: number, action: any) => state,
  b: (state: string, action: any) => state,
};
```

I'm trying to type this like so:

```
type StateSlices<T, K extends keyof T> = Record<
  keyof T,
  (state: T[K], action: any) => T[K]
>;
```

However, if I then try to write this:

```
const test: StateSlices<TestState, keyof TestState> = {
  a: (state: number, action: any) => state,
  b: (state: string, action: any) => state,
};
```

I get compilation errors, because Typescript doesn't know whether I mean to use strings or numbers:

```
Type '(state: number, action: any) => number' is not assignable to type '(state: string | number, action: any) => string | number'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
```

I can't work out how to type this correctly, and have tried all day to find a way, but no luck. Ultimately I would like to be able to specify the associated types for the actions as well as the state, but I'm leaving the actions as 'any' because I can't even get the state working.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

**EDIT**

As an additional question, If I'm trying to associate my different slices of state with specific actions, what might be the best way to do that?

For example:

```
const test: StateSlices<TestState, keyof TestState> = {
  a: (state: number, action: "ADD" | "SUBTRACT") => state,
  b: (state: string, action: "TO_LOWERCASE" | "TO_UPPERCASE") => state,
};
```

What would be the best way to associate slice 'a' of TestState with its associated actions, so that this would throw an error:

```
const test: StateSlices<TestState, keyof TestState> = {
  a: (state: number, action: "TO_LOWERCASE" | "SUBTRACT") => state,
  b: (state: string, action: "SUBTRACT" | "TO_UPPERCASE") => state,
};
```

Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mapped types:

```
interface TestState {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

type StateSlices<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (state: T[K], action: any) => T[K]
}

const test: StateSlices<TestState> = {
  a: (state, action) => state,
  b: (state, action) => state,
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gMpjpZAbwFgAoZZOALmRAFcBbAI2gG4yKmaspQBzdqQC+ZMmACeABxS58EbABtgSDAB5UAPmQBeIhwrIA2gGlkoZAGsI4gPYw0AXRoAKLHJqoTDgDSUEYYBsQGjgQcQBKHS1PYwcyEVIyBCCsZEgsGllIRWVMdUwcPEgtXRJyShc3SF9EAKDI7S0qiG99LmRXIpa-OpAGpq7W4VYgA)

**Appendix 1:** As for the second part of your question, you can use conditional types to obtain desired actions based on the type of your state. It will work, but it doesn't scale well.

```
interface TestState {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

type GetAction<T> =
  T extends number
    ? "ADD" | "SUBTRACT"
    : T extends string
      ? "TO_LOWERCASE" | "TO_UPPERCASE"
      : never;

type StateSlices<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (state: T[K], action: GetAction<T[K]>) => T[K]
}

const test: StateSlices<TestState> = {
  a: (state, action) => state,
  b: (state, action) => state,
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gMpjpZAbwFgAoZZOALmRAFcBbAI2gG4yKmaspQBzdqQC+ZMmACeABxQBxCGACCCMMAD2IADyoAfMgC8HNMggAPSCAAmGWoxZRDFAPzIARAoAi7l8gA+r7ACqAEKoAEoKAMKoLg7INKjGZhCW1jz8sU6uqADyAPoAMtkA6gCioREK2CXefi45uQEACo1lFVUx5BRdNCAQAG5soqQS0si4+BDYADbASBhaunpEsQDaANLIoMgA1hDiqjBoALo0ABRYE-HrRwA0lMpqIDRyig-qWtfaAJT6uqjXZBEpDICHUWGQkCwNHGkGms0wWkwODwkEWy061GQ5xREDuiBU6h+el0F0gN0MXCxpNx9wJICJJJx5OEgiAA)

**Appendix 2** You can also use this technique:

```
interface TestState {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

interface Actions {
  a: "ADD" | "SUBTRACT";
  b: "TO_LOWERCASE" | "TO_UPPERCASE";
}

type StateSlices<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (state: T[K], action: K extends keyof Actions ? Actions[K] : never) => T[K]
}

const test: StateSlices<TestState> = {
  a: (state, action) => state,
  b: (state, action) => state,
};
```

[Playgorund](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gMpjpZAbwFgAoZZOALmRAFcBbAI2gG4yKmaspQBzdqQC+ZMqEixEKAIIIwwAPYgMRDpRoAiaQBFtG5AB9kG7AFUAQqgBK0gMKoNgzptQB5APoAZVwHUAola20th++kYabu6mAArRAUEhjmQipGRgAJ4ADii4+BDYADbASBgAPKgAfMgAvKrkFMgA2gDSyKDIANYQ6QowaAC6NAAUWHk0qC39ADSUcoogNK0QAB6QIAAmKl09fbLySioA-Mh78xiTyDQgEABu0ACUNVUTzf3JoqQIB2DIkFg0uUghWKmHKmBweEgVVqJHq1GQI0hEBmiH2IEe1Sqo0gUzUXAR2ORszRGKxSNxwkEQA)

Comment: Thank you! As a bonus, how would you go about associating each slice of state with specific action types?

Comment: Please elaborate on what is the desired type of each `action` first.

Comment: I've just updated the question, any help would be really appreciated but very thankful for your answer which I'm marking as correct

Comment: Thank you very much!! I was trying to get it working using Extract but this is a massive help. I can finally move on from spending all day on it...